# Traverse Directory Depth First

Tags: c, posix

I need to traverse a directory depth first without using boost but I have not been able to find a good tutorial how to do this. I know how to list the files of the directory, but not sure how to about this one. This list the files of a directory:

Comment: Why negative vote?, listen if you cant point me towards a good tutorial.. just do not post.. or say anything.. I am new to this.. Is this how it is for everything here?

Comment: You need to ask a more specific question.  The only way to answer this as it is currently stated is to write it for you, which I don't think most of us really want to do....

Comment: so dont do it..All i asked was for a tutorial or guidance, I did not say DO IT FOR ME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ftw` or `nftw` functions if your system has them. Or, grab the [`fts_*`](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/OpenBSD/fts.3.html) functions from, e.g., the [OpenBSD source tree](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/lib/libc/gen/fts.c?rev=1.44) and study those, or use them directly. This problem is harder than you might think, because you can run out of file descriptors when recursing through deep filesystem hierarchies.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you understand [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29).

I assume you have a function `walk(dir_path)` which can list all files (and directries) in the dir_path directory. You need to modify it, so it calls it self (recursively) for each directory you find. That's it.